# Could not copy the file "obj\Debug \{project name.dll}" because it was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net

This error occurs immediately after building the project, I've tried changing the dot net framework from 4.6 to a lesser version it still does the same thing. 
Reinstalling visual studio 2015 doesn't still correct this issue.

Comment: Have you checked if there are any pre- or post-build events in the project properties of your project which are trying to copy the output file?

Comment: Where is projectname.dll located?

Comment: Located In the  "obj\Debug\" folder

Comment: you need to add the reference of the {Project name.dll} to your solution.

Comment: How do I add the reference to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your build path under project > properties> build > output ?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked.. It leads to the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you don't provide a lot of details so I am going to make some assumptions as I have seen this issue before and it can be a bit tricky.

It sounds to me like you have other issues.

You probably have another project being referenced by your main project. This second project is not building. That's what you need to focus on. Try and build only that project first, when that succeeds you can build your main project and this issue won't happen.

The way things work is like this.

You try to build your main project.

The compiler goes to the referenced projects and tries to build those first, if that succeeds then the dlls generated are copied over to the bin folder of the main project.

If my assumptions are incorrect then please edit your question and add all the details you can so we can actually help you.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, so what extra details do I need to provide? 
And I have only one window of visual studio open, how do I stop any other projects if open from trying to build

Comment: what is the structure of your application, how many projects are there, what references are there, what references each project has, which project causes this error.... help us help you basically.